# How to sort lines of text alphabetically based on a part of each line?

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr

I have a text file that contains abbreviations like so (simplified example):

```
\item[3D] Three-dimensional
\item[PCA] Principal Component Analysis
\item[RF] Random Forest
\item[ANN] Artificial Neural Networks
```

I want to manipulate these lines in `R` so that the abbreviations (e.g. ANN) are sorted in an alphabetical order and an abbreviation that starts with a number (e.g. 3D) comes after the last abbreviation that starts with letter. `\item[]`s should be ignored and left unmodified as they are going to be used in a `LaTeX` file.

My desired output is:

```
\item[ANN] Artificial Neural Networks
\item[PCA] Principal Component Analysis
\item[RF] Random Forest
\item[3D] Three-dimensional
```

I would be interested in solving this using `tidyverse` but any other solution will be useful too.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I agree, but this adds another "\" so lines start with "\\" which is not desired given that I have multiple pages of lines starting with "\". If could somehow manage to sort the lines alphabetically, and have lines start with "\\" I would need to delete one of the "\"s

Comment: I can assure you that reading the data from a file works — *nothing* will get added, the text will be read *as-is*. You are probably getting confused because when displaying strings, the R console doesn’t display the *value* of the string. Instead it shows its representation in R syntax. To show the *value*, use `writeLines(your_variable)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I updated my post and deleted the part where I was complaining about the `readlines()` thing. Because the main objective is to somehow get the desired output I have shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here’s a ‘tidyverse’ solution:

```
sorted_lines = readLines(your_file) %>%
    tibble(text = .) %>%
    extract(text, into = 'abbr', regex = r'(\\item\[([^]]*)\])', remove = FALSE) %>%
    arrange(abbr) %>%
    pull(text)
```

Result:

```
\item[3D] Three-dimensional
\item[ANN] Artificial Neural Networks
\item[PCA] Principal Component Analysis
\item[RF] Random Forest
```

However, there’s really no need to use tidy data manipulation here. You can equivalently use (mostly<sup>1</sup>) base R functions:

```
lines = readLines(your_file)
abbreviations = str_match(lines, r'(\\item\[([^\]]*)\])')[, 2L]
sorted_lines = lines[order(abbreviations)]
```

Note that both solutions produce a *different* ordering than in your question, because they will order “3D” *before* “ANN”, as is conventional. Are you sure you want to put numbers at the end?

In both cases, the code extracts the abbreviation from each line of text via the regular expression `r'(\\item\[([^]]*)\])'`, and then sorts the lines *by* these abbreviations.

The regular expression uses R 4.0’s new [raw string literals](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Quotes.html): `r"(…)"`. This allows us to use backslashes inside the string without having to escape them. Without raw string literals, the regular expression would look like this: `\\\\item\\[([^\\]]*)\\])`. — That’s just unnecessarily hard to read.

---

<sup>1</sup> I’m using `str_match` from ‘stringr’, since the pattern extraction functions in base R are a pain to use.

Comment: Additional upvote for your annotation regarding base R's regex functions. :D

Comment: Plus: first time I read about raw string literals. Good to know.

Comment: Works perfectly on 8 pages of abbreviations and saves a lot of time! :) PS.1: Having lines starting with numbers to be displayed first is fine. PS.2: I am glad you showed the base `R` approach as well, as this is indeed simple enough (arguably simpler than the `tidyverse` approach)